# Pulling Quarters from date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Please help me how can I break a date range into quarters of a year.Ex date range 1st Jan 2012 to 31st October 2013 should give me a result set of all 8 quarters.The results should be in following format, I am using SQL server 2008 :

```
Quarter Month start Month end

1   Jan-12  Mar-12
2   Apr-12  Jun-12
3   Jul-12  Sep-12
4   Oct-12  Dec-12
1   Jan-13  Mar-13
2   Apr-13  Jun-13
3   Jul-13  Sep-13
4   Oct-13  Oct-13
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to look at the `DATEPART(QUARTER,date)` and break them up that way. Something akin to this:

```
select datepart(year, dateTarget) as theYear, num as theQuarter, min(dateTarget) as startDate, max(dateTarget) as endDate
from numbers
join dates on datepart(quarter, dateper) = num
where num between 1 and 4
group by datepart(year, dateTarget),num
```

Where the `dates` table is the table you're looking at, and `numbers` is, well, a numbers table (something I find pretty useful to just have around).

Answer (score -1):

This gives you quarter start dates for 12 quarrters:

```
with calendar as (
  select 
    --DATEFROMPARTS(year(getdate()),1,1) as [start], 
    convert(datetime, convert(char(4), year(getdate()))+'0101') as [start], 
    qtrsBack = 1
  union all
  select  
    dateadd(mm,-3,[start]), 
    qtrsBack+1
  from calendar
  where qtrsback < 12
)
select * from calendar
```

producing:

```
start      qtrsBack
---------- -----------
2013-01-01 1
2012-10-01 2
2012-07-01 3
2012-04-01 4
2012-01-01 5
2011-10-01 6
2011-07-01 7
2011-04-01 8
2011-01-01 9
2010-10-01 10
2010-07-01 11
2010-04-01 12
```